# Link two different post using there post_id in post meta

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, customization, save-post

I  have a frontend form through which users can create custom posts(events in my case).

Now I am want to `fetch all address data` from that form and create a new post once that complete form is submitted by the user from the front end.

I am trying to use save_post to trigger my function in `function.php`.

But below function gives `500 error in console` and the page is frozen.

```
add_action( 'save_post','add_menu_custom_event');

function add_menu_custom_event($post_id) {
    //Check it's not an auto save routine
          if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
                return;

    //Perform permission checks! For example:
          if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
                return;
echo "post_id".$post_id;

$data = array (
     'post_title'    => 'New Title6',
     'post_type' => 'tribe_venue', 
     'meta_input'   => array (
          '_VenueAddress' => 'Address check', 
          '_VenueCity' => 'city check',
          '_VenueCountry' => 'Afghanistan',
          '_VenueProvince' =>  'province',  
          '_VenueZip' => '121007',
          '_VenuePhone' => '7503118112',
          '_VenueURL' => 'someurl.com',
          '_VenueShowMapLink' => 1,
     ),

);




//      save the new post
 $pid = wp_insert_post($data,true);  // gives 1536    _EventVenueID

 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_EventVenueID', $pid ); // i am trying to link parent post id to its child post id

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i GOT THE issues , here is my answer.

Now two posts are linked properly.
I just need to update the metadata dynamically.

```
add_action( 'save_post','add_menu_custom_event', 10, 3);

function add_menu_custom_event(  $post_id, $post, $update  ) {

     /*
     * In production code, $slug should be set only once in the plugin,
     * preferably as a class property, rather than in each function that needs it.
     */

     //Check it's not an auto save routine
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

    //Perform permission checks! For example:
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
      return;

    //if( false != $update )
     //d(get_current_screen( ));
     /d($update);
     //die; 

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

$_REQUEST['']

    // If this isn't a 'book' post, don't update it.
    if ( "tribe_events" != $post_type ) return;

    $data = array (
         'post_title'    => 'New Title6'.rand(1, 9999),
         'post_type' => 'tribe_venue', 
         'meta_input'   => array (
              '_VenueAddress' => 'Address check', 
              '_VenueCity' => 'city check',
              '_VenueCountry' => 'Afghanistan',
              '_VenueProvince' =>  'province',  
              '_VenueZip' => '121007',
              '_VenuePhone' => '7503118112',
              '_VenueURL' => 'someurl.com',
              '_VenueShowMapLink' => 1,
         ),

    );

  $pid = wp_insert_post($data,true);  

  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_EventVenueID', $pid );

}
```